# How to determine how many lines have been created in Table?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

How can be determined the amount of lines created on table within one process?

Answer (score 1):

Counting records is easy:

```
RecId c = (select count(RecId) from InventTable).RecId;
info(strFmt("%1", c));
```

Counting records of a process may be more difficult depending on your definition of a "process", as this is not an AX concept.

For tables where the `CreatedTransactionId` property have been enabled, you may count the number of records inserted in a transaction.

```
TransactionLog log;
RecId c;
ttsBegin;
log.insert();
c = (select count(RecId) from TransactionLog 
     where TransactionLog.createdTransactionId == appl.curTransactionId()).RecId;
info(strFmt("%1 %2", c, appl.curTransactionId()));
ttsAbort;
```

This uses the `appl.curTransactionId()` method which returns a non-zero value when records have been inserted in a table where the property is set. The value is incremented for each transaction.

In production code an index on `createdTransactionId` would be required for efficiency.

Comment: Hello Jan,

I will explain shortly what exactly I mean by "process"...
For example when I select product in "ProdTableListPage" form and press "Report as finished" button the "ProdParmReportAsFinished" form appears with selected product. On this form when we press "ok" button it begins to post 3 types of journals into the "ProdJournalTable" table. So by "process" I mean the moment when user press "ok" button till the end of posting and I want somehow to count if all 3 types of journals(picking list, route card and report as finished) have been posted successfully. 

Hope I explained it clearly

Comment: Then you have will to change the logic of the production journal classes to return the relevant numbers. It is not a standard feature. Look for classes called `Prod*Multi`. Make a method to return the number of posted journals (to be called after `run`).